# Jest failed because spyOn is still apply

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a nodejs under **nestjs** App, i have some testing on Pipe.
I follow this type of architecture https://github.com/mguay22/nestjs-mongo/tree/unit-testing/src/users.

My test **works correctly when i execute it one by one.** But when i execute all the files this will fails.

I know why, it's because for example inside the `spyOn` in the seconde test `(no offer is found)` the `spyOn` from the first test is executed. I found that is a common error, but i find nothing to solve it for me!

If i try **restore, reset, clear** afterEach this **continue to fails**, when i use resetAllMocks i have a slighty different error:

```
Property `getReservations` does not exist in the provided object
```

This is my acutal script (remove the others test to be readable):

```
  describe('ReservationIdsValidationPipe', () => {
      let createReservationPipe: CreateReservationPipe
      let publicLocationService: PublicLocationService
      let publicPricingService: PublicPricingService
      let publicOfferService: PublicOfferService
      let publicReservationService: PublicReservationService
    
      const requestMock = {
        params: {
          clientId: CLIENT_ID.VALID,
          storeId: STORE_ID.VALID,
        },
      }

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        CreateReservationPipe,
        {
          provide: PublicLocationService,
          useClass: PublicLocationServiceMock,
        },
        {
          provide: PublicOfferService,
          useClass: PublicOfferServiceMock,
        },
        {
          provide: PublicPricingService,
          useClass: PublicPricingServiceMock,
        },
        {
          provide: PublicReservationService,
          useClass: PublicReservationServiceMock,
        },
        {
          provide: REQUEST,
          useValue: requestMock,
        },
      ],
    }).compile()

    publicPricingService = moduleRef.get<PublicPricingService>(PublicPricingService)
    publicOfferService = moduleRef.get<PublicOfferService>(PublicOfferService)
    publicLocationService = moduleRef.get<PublicLocationService>(PublicLocationService)
    publicReservationService = moduleRef.get<PublicReservationService>(PublicReservationService)
    createReservationPipe = moduleRef.get<CreateReservationPipe>(CreateReservationPipe)
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  describe('Transform', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const slot = { start: '10:00', end: '10:30' } as unknown as Slot
      const pricing = { ...pricingStub(), _id: reservationStub().pricings[0].id } as PricingDocument

      jest.spyOn(publicReservationService, 'getReservations').mockResolvedValue([{ slot } as unknown as Reservation])
      jest.spyOn(publicPricingService, 'getPricings').mockResolvedValue([pricing])
    })
    it('should throw NotFoundException if no location is found', () => {
      jest.spyOn(publicLocationService, 'getLocation').mockRejectedValue(NotFoundException)
      expect(createReservationPipe.transform(reservationStub())).rejects.toThrow(
        new NotFoundException('Invalid location(id) inside body')
      )
    })

    it('should throw NotFoundException if no offer is found', () => {
      jest.spyOn(publicOfferService, 'getOffer').mockRejectedValue(NotFoundException)
      expect(createReservationPipe.transform(reservationStub())).rejects.toThrow(
        new NotFoundException('Invalid offer(id) inside body')
      )
    })
  })
})
```

The only way that can works and the two test passed is doing this:

```
it('should throw NotFoundException if no location is found', () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(publicLocationService, 'getLocation').mockRejectedValue(NotFoundException)
      expect(createReservationPipe.transform(reservationStub())).rejects.toThrow(
        new NotFoundException('Invalid location(id) inside body')
      )
      spy.mockReset()
    })
```

But this is not really pratical on a lot of test, and it's create a new error in others test ...

This is a example of a mock:

```
import { locationStub } from '../test/stubs/location.stub'

export const PublicLocationService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  getLocation: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(locationStub()),
  getLocations: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([locationStub()]),
})
```

*Version: "jest": "^29.7.0", "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0"*

```
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@framework/(.*)$': ['<rootDir>/src/framework/$1'],
    '^@database/(.*)$': ['<rootDir>/src/database/$1'],
    '^@test/(.*)$': ['<rootDir>/src/test/$1'],
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/dist'],
  clearMocks: true,
  restoreMocks: true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are sharing spies across multiple test cases. When you use jest.spyOn and mock values, the spy remains "active" across different test cases unless you explicitly reset or clear it. You can move the setup of spies to a beforeAll hook to ensure they are set up once for all test cases. Then use the afterEach hook to reset or clear the spies after each test case. Try something like this,

```js
describe('ReservationIdsValidationPipe', () => {
  ...

  const requestMock = {
    params: {
      ...
    },
  }

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      // ... your providers setup
    }).compile()

    publicPricingService = moduleRef.get<PublicPricingService>(PublicPricingService)
    publicOfferService = moduleRef.get<PublicOfferService>(PublicOfferService)
    publicLocationService = moduleRef.get<PublicLocationService>(PublicLocationService)
    publicReservationService = moduleRef.get<PublicReservationService>(PublicReservationService)
    createReservationPipe = moduleRef.get<CreateReservationPipe>(CreateReservationPipe)
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  describe('Transform', () => {
    // ... your test cases
  })
})
```

Also if possible, consider separating your tests into individual test suites. Each test suite can have its own beforeEach and afterEach hooks. Something like this,

```js
describe('ReservationIdsValidationPipe', () => {
  // ... common setup

  describe('Test Suite 1', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // ... setup for suite 1
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks()
    })

    it('should do something', () => {
      // ... test logic
    })
  })

  describe('Test Suite 2', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // ... setup for suite 2
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks()
    })

    it('should do something else', () => {
      // ... test logic
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I try the both way combine but i ended up with the second test failing, ```Expected message: "Invalid offer(id) inside body" Received message: "Invalid location(id) inside body"```.

If i comment the first test for example, the second will passed.
I really not understand why the clear not works as expected ...